# Appending dataframe to existing Excel worksheet using Openpyxl

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying to create a new spreadsheet and worksheet containing the column headings from a dataframe.  I then want to append new data to the worksheet every `For` loop iteration.  I am likely to have a large amount of data and therefore thought it would be necessary to write it out to Excel after every iteration rather than writing the whole DF at the end.
The *"Append data to existing worksheet"* code in the `For` loop works correctly (ie gives me 3 rows of values) on its own if I am writing to a spreadsheet that already contains the column headings that I have created within Excel. But when I run the code as you see below, I only end up with the column headings and the values from the last `For` loop iteration.  I'm obviously missing something simple but can't seem to work it out.  Any help would be much appreciated

```
import openpyxl as xl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

fn = '00test101.xlsx'
# Create new workbook
wb = xl.Workbook()
wb.save(fn)

book = xl.load_workbook(fn)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fn,engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
# Write DF column names to new worksheet
DF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])
DF.to_excel(writer, 'ABC', header=True, startrow=0)
writer.save()

for i in range(3):
    a = np.array([1,3,6]) * i

    # Overwrite existing DF and add data
    DF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])
    DF.loc[dt.datetime.now()] = a

    # Append data to existing worksheet
    book = xl.load_workbook(fn)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fn,engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
    DF.to_excel(writer, 'ABC', header=None, startrow=book.active.max_row)
    writer.save()

# Remove unwanted default worksheet
wb = xl.load_workbook(fn)
def_sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
wb.remove_sheet(def_sheet)
wb.save(fn)
```

Comment: I think your problem comes from `startrow=book.active.max_row`, replace by `startrow=book['ABC'].max_row` and it should work

Comment: and for more explanation, it's because you have the default sheet in your book when performing your loop `for` and this one seems to be the active one. If you delete it (as you do at the end) before getting in your loop for, I assume you won't get your problem when using `active`

Comment: Just use http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html

Comment: Yeah both of your points are exactly right thanks @Ben.T. I had assumed the sheet I was writing to was 'active' by default